# How can I do like this photo ? What is the module using by python

Tags: python

How can I print characters like this photo?

[image]

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

[pyfiglet](https://github.com/pwaller/pyfiglet) should do it. [Font](http://www.figlet.org/examples.html) in your picture seems to be close to doom.

```
from pyfiglet import Figlet
f = Figlet(font='doom')
print(f.renderText('recond'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's called ASCII Art, and I use [TOIlet](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/toilet) for it.